# Parsing JSON string with value from object that is in array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, parsing

I am using Postgresql 9.6 and here is a json:

```
{"items":[{"id":32,"title":"test"}]}
```

It's from a database table named **random** with a column name *things*. So I managed to get only first object, which in my case is (I assume..?) `{"id":32,"title":"test"}`with this code:

```
SELECT things::jsonb-> 'items'->> 0
FROM random
```

What I'm trying to get is only the number of id. 
I tried to go deeper into object, but as I understood I cannot, because of integer 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `->` operator to get the first array element as a JSON object, then you can navigate to the `id` key:

```
SELECT things::jsonb-> 'items'-> 0 ->> 'id'
FROM random;
```

Comment: That works well, but only for the first row. Edited question. But thanks!

Comment: @oskaras_ka: what do you mean with "first row"? Rows in the table? Elements in the array?

Comment: Rows in the table under "things" column like this '{"items":[{"id":32,"title":"test"}]}', {"items":[{"id":33,"title":"test"}]} and etc. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @oskaras_ka: you need to supply a complete set of sample data if your question doesn't really reflect want you want to do. Ideally as a script with `create table` and `insert` statements.